# How to use paramatrization in java?

Tags: java

I have this java code which uses `<T>`:

```
public static class mySet<T> extends Set {

    // Define a list object using parametric polymorphism
    public final List<T> set;

    // Define the constructor for a Set data type
    public <T> mySet(List<T> given_set) {
        this.set = (List<T>) given_set;
    }
}
```

however I get an error here `(List<T>) given_set;`.
It should work because I am making it the same type as the final variable set, but it doesn't.

Does anyone know why?

Eclipse is saying: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.util.List<T> to java.util.List<T>`.

Comment: see above for the error message.

Comment: Please note that you should have posted the error message in the first place. Omitting it just wastes time. You're going to be asked for it, and the question is meaningless without it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't making it the same type. By using `<T>` in front of the constructor declaration, you are introducing a *new* `T`, with no type relationship to the class's `T`. Remove it. Then you can remove the cast as well, it does nothing.